# I inserted my serialization code and then got and error. How can I get the right page rendered?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

The code I inserted is below and under it is the error.. not sure why I am getting the error when the tutorial gets the right page.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
  User.findById(id, function(err,user){
    done(err,user);
  });
});
```

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: userDB.users 
index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }
    at Function.create (C:\Users\user\Desktop\angelas web dev 2021\webdev\backend\Secrets\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:57:12)
    at toError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\angelas web dev 2021\webdev\backend\Secrets\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123:22)     
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\angelas web dev 2021\webdev\backend\Secrets\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:258:39
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\angelas web dev 2021\webdev\backend\Secrets\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:405:18    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Comment: the problem is about you try to insert `{ username: null }` in the database,The error message is saying that there's already a record with null as the username. In other words, you already have a user without an username

Comment: Oh, so if i log in, everything will be fine....